# Get number of lines for specific varchar in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

In MS SQL Server 2012 I have a database with a table containing a varchar column that holds some text that might even include line breaks.

Basic example:

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    [ID] INT
  , [Text] VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Example ([ID], [Text])
VALUES
        (1, 'This is a test'),
        (2, 'This is another
         test with
         two line breaks'),
        (3, 'This is a test
         with one line break');
```

Now I want to get the total lines of text for each record, i.e., something like this:

```
--------------------
| ID | LinesOfText |
--------------------
|  1 |           1 |
--------------------
|  2 |           3 |
--------------------
|  3 |           2 |
--------------------
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a built-in functions for something like this. My idea was to count `Chr(10)+Chr(13)` occurrences and add 1 at the end. But `CHARINDEX` only finds the first occurrence in a string.

Any idea how to solve this?

**Extra information that might be useful**: To give a deeper insight to my data, the "Text" is coming from a XML string that contains line breaks, e.g.

```
...
<a>This is
   another test
   with two line breaks</a>
...
```

I use `CROSS APPLY XML.nodes(...` and XPath to find all `<a>` nodes in the XML. Could this be solved directly with T-SQL XML functions?

Comment: Thanks, already changed it. I copied it from sqlfiddle.com but wasn't aware I am in MySQL mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Replace` to eliminate the line breaks through replacing with nothing (`''`). Then you can substract the lengh of the modified text from the original.

Comment: How can I count non-blank lines?

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
select id, text,LEN(Text)-LEN(replace(text,char(10),''))+1 LinesOfText
from Example
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '<p>
<a>This is a test</a>
<a>This is
     another test
     with two line breaks</a>
<a>This is a test
     with one line break</a>
</p>'

SELECT 
      id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    , LinesOfText = LEN(txt) - LEN(REPLACE(txt, CHAR(10), '')) + 1
FROM (
    SELECT txt = t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    FROM @XML.nodes('p/a') t(c)
) t
```

**Output:**

```
id                   LinesOfText
-------------------- --------------------
1                    1
2                    3
3                    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, LEN() and REPLACE() is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing clever about this approach, and I think the examples using replace are more elegant, but this is fairly belt and braces:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_LinesOfText(@Text varchar(MAX)) Returns INT As
Begin
    Declare @Result int, @LastOffset int

    SET @LastOffset=0
    SET @Result=1   
    SET @LastOffset=CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @Text, @LastOffset)
    WHILE @LastOffset>=1 BEGIN
        SET @Result=@Result+1
        SET @LastOffset=CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) ,@Text,  @LastOffset+1)
    END

    Return @Result
End
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to implement my first approach, this could also be useful for others who want to write their own function.

Comment: This worked well for me. I changed varchar(MAX) to nvarchar(MAX) in the incoming parameters.  Thank you Kevin.